# SQL - SELECT from a table if a certain condition is met, else SELECT from another

Tags: sql, db2

How do I do this in SQL:

1. `SELECT CLIENT, PAYMENT_CODE FROM PAYMENTS_TABLE`
2. `If PAYMENT_CODE = 1, SELECT other data from table_1`
3. `Else, SELECT other data from table_2`

The results I want are:

```
| Client | Payment Code = 1 | Address from table_1 | Phone from table_1 | ...
```

or

```
| Client | Payment Code  1 | Address from table_2 | Phone from table_2 | ...
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: -1 for using every db tag you could find and not showing any effort

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? You should only tag the ones you are using. There are a number of ways to accomplish what you are asking but it can vary the best approach based on the DBMS.

Comment: Which RDMS do you use?

Comment: I'm sure a couple of left joins and `CASE` expressions will accomplish this in any database supporting standard SQL.

Comment: @JohnConde I'm sorry about the tags, I'm new here and I thought of using every db tag I could find so that I'd see how many variations of the answer I would get. It's a fairly general question after all, but one I couldn't solve after spending half a day googling it,  browsing stackoverflow and adapting the answers I found. Anyway, I won't use so many tags anymore. As for not showing any effort, what do you mean?

Comment: @SeanLange I use DB2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't tell us how table_1 and table_2 are linked to payments_table, but something like this should work:

```
select p.client, 
       p.payment_code,
       case 
          when payment_code = 1 then t1.address
          else t2.address
       end as address,
       case 
          when payment_code = 1 then t1.phone
          else t2.phone
       end as phon
from payments_table p
   left join table_1 t1 on p.some_column = t1.some_column
   left join table_2 t2 on p.some_column = t2.come_column
```

Comment: First of all, thanks for the edits. table_1, table_2 and payments_table are linked by client_code. I'm trying to edit my question to add this and the db2 tag but I keep getting a "your post appears to contain code that is not formatted properly", even though I'm only using pseudocode. Any tips?

Answer (score 2):

Although Rajesh's solution is fine, you can also do it using two LEFT JOINs;

```
SELECT pt.CLIENT, pt.PAYMENT_CODE, 
       COALESCE(t1.address, t2.address) address, 
       COALESCE(t1.phone,   t2.Phone)   phone
FROM PAYMENTS_TABLE pt
LEFT JOIN Table_1 t1 
  ON pt.client_code = t1.client_code AND pt.PAYMENT_CODE =  1
LEFT JOIN Table_2 t2 
  ON pt.client_code = t2.client_code AND pt.PAYMENT_CODE <> 1
```

EDIT: Added `client_code` as linking criteria according to a comment to another answer.

Answer (score 1):

you need to use `UNION` , one `SELECT` query to get details from table_1 when payment_code =1 and another `SELECT` to get details from table_2 when payment_code is not equal to 1

```
SELECT CLIENT, PAYMENT_CODE, T1.Address, T1.Phone FROM PAYMENTS_TABLE
JOIN Table_1 T1
ON -- your condition
WHERE PAYMENT_CODE =1
UNION 
SELECT CLIENT, PAYMENT_CODE, T2.Address, T2.Phone FROM PAYMENTS_TABLE
JOIN Table_2 T2
ON -- your condition
WHERE PAYMENT_CODE <> 1
```